# How to specify JDK version in Jenkinsfile pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline script to deploy applications to server. I'm building project using maven, I want Jenkins to use specified JDK version for building the project. My pipeline script looks like this:

```
pipeline {
agent any

tools {
    // Install the Maven version configured as "M3" and add it to the path.
    maven "Maven 3.6.3"
}

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {

            // Run Maven on a Unix agent.
            sh "mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -U"

        }

        post {
            // If Maven was able to run the tests, even if some of the test
            // failed, record the test results and archive the jar file.
            success {
                archiveArtifacts "**/${war}"
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy EQM Instance 1') {
        steps {
            sshagent(credentials: ['credentials']) {
                sh "echo 1"
                sh "echo Initializing deployment to Instance 1"
                sh "scp target/${war} ${bastionHost}:/home/opc"
                sh "echo 2.1"
                sh "echo Uploaded war file to bastion instance"
                sh "scp ${bastionHost}:/home/opc/${war} opc@${instanceDns}:/home/opc"
                sh "echo 3.2"
                sh "echo Uploaded war file from bastion instance to Instance 1 ${instanceDns}"
                sh "echo Undeploying old war file"
                sh "ssh ${bastionHost} -tt ssh opc@${instanceDns} sudo rm /opt/tomcat/webapps/${war}"
                sh "echo 4.2.2"
                sh "ssh ${bastionHost} -tt ssh opc@${instanceDns} sudo chown tomcat:tomcat -R ${war}"
                sh "echo Deploying new war file"
                sh "ssh ${bastionHost} -tt ssh opc@${instanceDns} sudo mv ${war} /opt/tomcat/webapps/"
                sh "echo 4.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are other already configured on Jenkins, I don't want to disturb them. So I want to specify JDK version in desired job configuration.

Comment: Just add to `tools` `jdk "myjdkID"`,  with whatever you have in Global Tools for JDK. Or use [toolchains.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)